# sass error: "No such file or directory"

Tags: sass

I am using sass and I just got the weird error and I have no idea how to resolve it.

As usual I am using the command line in order to watch my sass files:

```
sass --watch scss:resources/public/stylesheets
```

The problem is that I moved the folders `sass` and `public` for the new project.

When I try:

```
sass --watch scss:resources/public/stylesheets
```

I get this error:

```
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
      error No such file or directory - scss
Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory - resources/public/stylesheets
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

I have no idea why, because I am running that same command line in the old project and works perfectly.

The only difference between the first one that worked and this one that has the error is that the one with the error was copy and pasted.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `scss` and `resources/public/stylesheets` *exist*, *are directories*, and *are readable* from the folder where you're running `sass`? Literally, does `ls -ld scss resources/public/stylesheets` show what you expect?

Comment: Is your directory named 'sass' or 'scss'?  You say you moved the 'sass' directory, but you're specifying 'scss' in the command.

Comment: maybe you don't have enough permissions for that folder?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have folder name with **scss** not **sass**

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this & found that for whatever reason sass --watch was running off a css file that wasn't within a folder, it was just hanging out in the root dir. Just delete the css file & re-run sass --watch & it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, figured I had to make sure I created a SCSS and CSS folder first for Sass to watch. Having separate folders did the trick. Then I placed my Scss file in its folder and vice versa.